# List<T> Add method does not work in Button.Click event but it works in Form.Load

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, datagridview

I'm trying to make a program that works as a parking lot.

I worked so far with a few features and everything worked fine until I tried to add a new car in the parking lot.

I tried to use the add method in this case but I cant find the problem. Although it works properly when I use the method in Form_Load event it doesn't work in the `Button_Click` event handler.

My Class is this:

```
class Parking
{
    public int Spot { get; set; }
    public string Plate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnterTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExitTime { get; set; }

    public Parking(int spot, string plate, DateTime enterTime)
    {
        Spot = spot;
        Plate = plate;
        EnterTime = enterTime;
        ExitTime = null;
    }
}
```

My code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer clock = new Timer();

    List<Parking> parking = new List<Parking>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetLoadDataBase();
    }
    
    private void GetLoadDataBase()
    {
        parking.AddRange(new List<Parking>
        {
            new Parking(1, "TKN1893", DateTime.Now),            
            new Parking(2, "TKN1951", DateTime.Now),
            new Parking(3, "TNA725", DateTime.Now),
            new Parking(4, "TNA725", DateTime.Now),
            new Parking(5, "TNA725", DateTime.Now),
            new Parking(6, "TNA725", DateTime.Now),
            new Parking(7, "TNA725", DateTime.Now),
            new Parking(8, "TNA725", DateTime.Now)
        });                     
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clock.Interval = 1000;
        clock.Tick += new EventHandler(this.clock_Tick);
        clock.Start();

        *parking.Add(new Parking(10, "IP3147", DateTime.Now));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = parking;            
    }              

    private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string spot = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string plate = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string enterTime = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            ExitTimeInsert(e.RowIndex, parking);
            string exitTime = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            string BoxText = spot + " " + plate + " " + enterTime + " " + exitTime;

            DialogResult charge = MessageBox.Show(BoxText, "Test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (charge == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                parking[e.RowIndex] = null;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                parking[e.RowIndex].ExitTime = null;                    
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Spot is Empty!");
        }
    }

    private void ExitTimeInsert(int index, List<Parking> parking)
    {
        parking[index].ExitTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get current time
        int hh = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int mm = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        int ss = DateTime.Now.Second;

        //time
        string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToLongDateString();
        string time = "";

        //padding leading zero
        if (hh < 10)
        {
            time += "0" + hh;
        }
        else
        {
            time += hh;
        }
        time += ":";

        if (mm < 10)
        {
            time += "0" + mm;
        }
        else
        {
            time += mm;
        }
        time += ":";

        if (ss < 10)
        {
            time += "0" + ss;
        }
        else
        {
            time += ss;
        }

        //update label
        label1.Text = time;
        label2.Text = date;
    }

    private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Input_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        **Parking Adition = new Parking(10, "IP3147", DateTime.Now);
        **parking.Add(Adition);
        **parking.Add(new Parking(10, "IP3147", DateTime.Now));
        **Add_Record(textBox1.Text);
        **dataGridView1.DataSource = parking;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void Add_Record(string value)
    {
        **parking.Add(new Parking(10, value, DateTime.Now));
        **dataGridView1.DataSource = parking;
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense:

"*" "Implemetations That worked"
"**" "Implemetations tried separately not all together that didn't work"

Everything else works fine.

Comment: I know I just wanted you to have the full picture in case I messed up somewhere else.

Comment: yes i understand. however, you should have tried to prove that your self by commenting out every bit you don't need, until you find a minimal complete verifiable example. Then the idea is you come to us, and ask (with a few lines of code) why you see a certain behavior... This not only shows you have tried to seriously debug your work, it makes it easier for us, and gets your answer quicker... in fact sometimes you will find you can figure it out before you finish the question.. Anyway just suggestions for future

Comment: Thanks all tips are welcome 

Comment: In `Input_Button_Click` if you do `parking.Add(new Parking(10, "IP3147", DateTime.Now));` and `dataGridView1.Refresh();` does that not work?

Comment: Unfortunately no I tried that too. You basically see that the dataGridView1.refresh(); triggers but no new data in it

Comment: Have you copied/pasted the button control dragged from toolbox or generated it automatically ? have a look at  your form designer.cs sometimes you end up with a Input_Button1_Click which is the event of your Input_Button

Comment: I used the designer and drag dropped the button in the form and changed the name through properties before I created the click event. In Designer.cs all references are ok. As Input_Button also I get no errors by intellisense

Comment: In your `Button.Click()` event, set the DGV DataSource to null before setting the updated one: `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` `dataGridView1.DataSource = parking;`. No need to Refresh(), this repaints the UI. In `Form.Load()`, the DGV has no DataSource (it's already null).

Comment: Jimi can you rewrite this as an answer it worked perfectly for me thank you!

Comment: I added a description on how to use a BindingList. I think it would help, here. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the DataSource of DataGridView is a standard `List<T>`, changes on the `List<T>` content are not automatically reflected in the DataGridView: the `List<T>` will not send update notifications.
Re-setting the DataSource property of the DataGridView to the same `List<T>` won't refresh the data either, because the DataSource object reference is actually the same.

It can be seen in the .Net source:  [DataGridView.DataSource property setter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2404).

```
set
{
    if (value != this.DataSource) { ...  }
```

`value` is `=` to `this.DataSource`: the DataSource is the same, so no action is performed.

Setting the DataSource property to `null` then again to the previous `List<T>` will reset the DataSource.

Another option, probably preferable, is to use a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.ComponentModel.BindingList%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of a `List<T>`.

> The `BindingList<T>` class can be used as a base class to create a
>   two-way data-binding mechanism. `BindingList<T>` provides a concrete,
>   generic implementation of the `IBindingList` interface.

Let's get this to work using the current setup:

1. Add **`Parking`** elements to the BindingList (Form Constructor or `Form.Load`)
2. Set the `DataGridView.DataSource` property to the BindingList object.

Using a `BindingList` is almost the same as using a standard `List<T>`.
Notice that when you add or remove an element from the `BindingList`, the DataGridView is updated immediately without requiring any further action:

[image: DataGridView BindingList]

```
private BindingList<Parking> parking = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var tmpList = new List<Parking>
    {
        new Parking(1, "TKN1893", DateTime.Now),
        new Parking(2, "TKN1951", DateTime.Now),
        new Parking(3, "TNA725", DateTime.Now),
    };
    this.parking = new BindingList<Parking>();
    tmpList.ForEach(elm => parking.Add(elm));
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //(...)
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.parking;            
}              

private void btnAddRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.parking.Add(new Parking(10, "IP3147", DateTime.Now));
}

private void btnRemoveRecord(string value)
{
    this.parking.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Jimi that is an excellent example thank you very much. I will try it for sure. 

Comment: If there are no other *implications* in your code, a `BindingList` provides automatic, bi-directional, updates. Thus, you can also remove a Row from the DataGridView: it will be reflected in the `BindingList`. It behaves more or less like a DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap the `dataGridView1` with an `UpdatePanel` and add the `Input_Button` as a `trigger`. Make sure that the `dataGridView1.Refresh()` is called within the `Input_Button_Click` method.

Comment: Isn't UpdatePanel a Web.UI control?  Can you please show an example? Thank you 

Comment: You didn't specify that you are working on `winforms`. Adding `forms` alone can mean `webforms` too.